# What type of Paging is used when 32-bit linux runs on 64 bit Intel architecture?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What type of Paging is used when 32-bit linux runs on 64 bit Intel architecture?

```
(1) 32-bit Paging  
(2) PAE Paging  
(3) IA-32e Paging
```

In other words, What kind of paging is used in which situation?

Comment: Notice that most x86-64 Linux kernels are able to run x86 32 bits Linux executables.

Comment: Also, is this a homework question? If so, you should use the `homework` tag -- we can still help, but it will help us guide how to answer.

Comment: This is not my homework question, I am reading Intel Manual Vol 3A and trying to understand paging mechanism in details..

Answer (score 4):

Either 32-bit or PAE, depending on what variety of 32-bit kernel it is. In other words, it behaves no differently than if it were running on a 32-bit CPU.

Comment: "depending on what variety of 32-bit kernel it is" - can you elaborate more on this ...

Comment: 32-bit Linux kernels can be configured with or without PAE support.